# How do I embed global React components in Docusaurus v2?

Tags: reactjs, components, global, docusaurus, mdxjs

I see that it is possible to embed React components with MDX:
https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/#embedding-react-components-with-mdx

However, this method works for a specific page. How can I make it work for all markdown files in the docs? I am trying to add a similar component as in the link above to change the style of some inline text. I tried to edit src/pages/index.js but it didn't work.

```
const HighlightGreen = (children) => (
  <span
    style={{
      backgroundColor: '#00a400', // green,
      borderRadius: '2px',
      color: '#fff',
      padding: '0.2rem',
    }}>
    {children}
  </span>
);
```

Comment: What is all markdown files "in the user manual"?

Comment: @YangshunTay I meant the "docs". I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

> However, this method works for a specific page.

In the [documentation](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/react) there is the example where you can create a file for component:

```js
// src/components/Highlight.js
import React from 'react';

export default function Highlight({children, color}) {
  return (
    <span
      style={{
        backgroundColor: color,
        borderRadius: '2px',
        color: '#fff',
        padding: '0.2rem',
      }}>
      {children}
    </span>
  );
}
```

It can be used in any page but you should add a reference:

```
import Highlight from '@site/src/components/Highlight';

<Highlight color="#25c2a0">Docusaurus green</Highlight>
```

So, you may define component once in a file and use it.

---

If you mean that you want to omit `import` statement and use component with implicit import then only way to do it in the theme. [Documentation](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/react#mdx-component-scope) says:

> If you want to register extra tag names (like the  tag above), you should consider wrapping @theme/MDXComponents, so you don't have to maintain all the existing mappings. Since the swizzle CLI doesn't allow wrapping non-component files yet, you should manually create the wrapper:

```js
import React from 'react';
// Import the original mapper
import MDXComponents from '@theme-original/MDXComponents';
import Highlight from '@site/src/components/Highlight';

export default {
  // Re-use the default mapping
  ...MDXComponents,
  // Map the "<Highlight>" tag to our Highlight component
  // `Highlight` will receive all props that were passed to `<Highlight>` in MDX
  Highlight,
};
```

@brendangibson [provides commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259892/3364871) for creating theme.

Answer (score 0):

It seems now you could "swizzle" the root component, by creating a `website/src/theme/Root.js` file, according to: https://docusaurus.io/docs/using-themes#wrapper-your-site-with-root

Comment: How do you modify Root.js to include the global components?

Answer (score 0):

`yarn swizzle @docusaurus/theme-classic MDXComponents --danger`

In `src/theme/MDXComponents/index.js`:

```
import {MyComponent} from "/src/components/MyComponent";
...
const MDXComponents = {
    MyComponent,
    ...
```